# Python: How to get exception as an object from a string with the same name?

Tags: python, string, exception, inheritance, subclass

Imagine I have strings containing names of exceptions:

```
s1 = 'KeyError'
s2 = 'ArithmeticError'
s3 = 'OSError'
s4 = 'ZeroDivisionError'
.....
sn = 'SomeOtherError'
```

What I need to do is:

```
if issubclass(s4, (s1, s2, s3, sn)) == True:
print('You dont have to catch this exception because the parent is already caught')
```

Using `globals()` doesn't help in this case for some reason. Since I am not an experienced programmer, I can only guess that it's because those are built-in exceptions...

Nevertheless, what can be done to accomplish what I try to accomplish?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason why you have the exceptions as strings in the first place?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi They come as strings from user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way is probably to search the class hierarchy. All built-in exceptions are ultimately descendants of `BaseException`, so just search its children recursively:

```py
def find_child_class(base, name):
  if base.__name__ == name:
    return base

  for c in base.__subclasses__():
    result = find_child_class(c, name)
    if result:
      return result
```

```py
>>> find_child_class(BaseException, 'KeyError')
<class 'KeyError'>
```

This will also work for user-defined exceptions, as long as the module that defines them has been loaded and the exceptions are derived from `Exception` (which they should be).

Answer (score -1):

`globals()` will work, if you use it the right way:

```
getattr(globals()['__builtins__'], 'KeyError')
<class 'KeyError'>
```

Comment: This might look like it works, but it fails in any module but `__main__`. Also, `__builtins__` is an implementation detail. It'd make way more sense to just [import the `builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Comment: (Even if the code in this answer *was* reliable, there wouldn't be any point going through `globals()` to get at `__builtins__` when you could just write `__builtins__`.)